# Object reference not set to an instance of an object hiddenfield

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field

I'm having a problem with my code

here is my master page html code

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>  
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="header" id="header">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
<asp:HiddenField ID="param1" runat="server" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function alertMessage() {
             var test = document.getElementById("param1").value;
             alert(test);
         }
     </script>
</div> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my code that called the hiddenfield on the child page

```
Protected Button1_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim param1 As HiddenField = DirectCast(Page.Master.FindControl("param1"), HiddenField)
    param1.Value = "Testing"
    Dim csname1 As String = "ClientScript"
    Dim csname2 As String = "alertMessage()"
    Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()

    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

    If (Not cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1)) Then
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, csname1, csname2, True)
    End If
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, csname2, True)
End Sub
```

It keep said Object reference not set to an instance of an object

here is the line of code that keep throwing an error

```
Dim param1 As HiddenField = DirectCast(Page.Master.FindControl("param1"), HiddenField)
```

Could anyone help me???

Appreciate all kind of help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Dim param1 As HiddenField =  Me.Page.Master.FindControl("param1")
```

then assing value to that control.basically when you are using hidden filed value before 
assign value to it this error come.